ref.listen is called even though the previous and next values are the same (riverpod)
I have a pretty basic usage of ref.listen(). I want to show a bottomSheet once the value of my provider changes.
ref.listen<MyObject?>(myObjectProvider, (previous, next) {
  debugPrint("showBottomSheet: ${previous == next}");
});

The following is printed:

showBottomSheet: false


showBottomSheet: true


showBottomSheet: true


showBottomSheet: true

The initial value is null that is why we get the first false.
My understanding is that next has to be different from previous for the listener to be called.

Riverpod uses identical instead of == to filter updates on notifiers. When the object exposed by the provider is changed, identical(previous, next) will return false, which is why the provider notifies its listeners and cause your ref.listen callback to fire.
See: Why does Riverpod use identical instead of == to filter updates in some cases?

You can still change this behavior by overriding the updateShouldNotify method on the notifier:
@riverpod
class MyObjectNotifier extends _$MyObjectNotifier {
  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(MyObject previous, MyObject next) {
    return previous != next;
  }

  // ...



See also:

identical function - Dart API

